# Replace input strings and integers

Tags: python

I need to write a function that takes a string (str), and two other strings (call it replace1 and replace2), and an integer (n). The function shall return a new string, where all the string inputs from replace1 in the first string (str) and replace the new string with replace1 depending on where you want the new input. I am not supposed to use built-in functions, but I can use lens (we can suppose that replace1 has the length 1). Example ( call it replaceChoice):

```
>>> replaceChoice(“Mississippi”, “s”, “l”, 2)
'Mislissippi'
```

I hope that I explained it well. Here is my attempt:

```
def replaceChoice(str1, replace1,n): 
newString=""
  for x in str:
      if x=="str1":
        newString=newString+replace 
  else:
       newString=newString+x 
  return newString
```

Comment: Where is the `replace2` parameter in your attempt?

Comment: What happens when you call your function as you've written it there? I suspect not much even if the indentation is fixed, because it'll error when it reaches `newString=newString+replace` because you don't pass `replace` as an argument

Comment: You also don't indicate explicitly what you use the integer argument `n` for, though it looks like it's the position you want to insert (i.e. your example should replace the second `s` in the string with the proposed character). Obvious homework is obvious.

Comment: @The_nice_doge you should accept the answer if it answers your question.

Answer (score 1):

I assume from your question that you want to replace the nth occurrence of r1 with r2.
Is this what you want?

```
>>> def replaceChoice(str1, r1, r2, n):
...     new_str = ""
...     replaced = False
...     for i in str1:
...             if i==r1:
...                     n-=1
...             if n==0 and not replaced:
...                     replaced = True
...                     new_str+=r2
...             else:
...                     new_str+=i
...     return new_str
... 
>>> replaceChoice("Mississippi", "s", "l", 2)
'Mislissippi'
```

Comment: Strictly speaking `range` is a python `built in` function. You can do it with `for i in str1` and swap out the value of `i` with`r2` when `n == 0`

Comment: @RolfofSaxony Edited.